# Order Total not updating after I change the line item price

Tags: commerce

I have a custom form which on submit creates a new order, loads a product and a custom line item type. I then save the information from the form in the line item. The line item price is updated via a rule which calls a custom PHP function. The problem is when I redirect to checkout/order_id the **Order Total** is not updated.

I've tried altering the order directly using my order_wrapper and i've also tried using commerce_price_component_add. I tried a rule which called "Save entity" again but nothing seems to be working.

Can somebody give me a point in the right direction on how to get the order total to re-calculate.

Also if anyone has any good examples of creating orders using custom line item types from a custom form that may be helpful

Answer (score 4):

The solution was to use `commerce_price_add_component()`

```
    $line_item_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper("commerce_line_item", $commerce_line_item);
    $line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->data = commerce_price_component_add(
        $line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->value(),
        'base_price',
        array(
                'amount' => $booking_price,
                'currency_code' => 'AUD',
                'data' => array(),
        ),
        TRUE
);
}
```

Comment: Then, inside commerce_cart_product_add(), do you insert the line item or the wrapper?

Comment: @Strae I always use the line item you could also use wrapper->value()

Comment: sorry but i dont get how to make it works. I have a sample code like that: http://pastebin.com/Fqn3GP5y the line item get inserted into the cart, but with the product original price and not with the manually one '12.34'!
Any suggestion?

Comment: @Strae This is only part of the issue. You still need to update the price inside the hook: hook_commerce_cart_line_item_refresh(), or via the proper RULE. Commerce needs to recalculate the price based upon the product before displaying the cart. So, unless you update it here, your price will simply be thrown out.