# How to add custom line item total to order total amount?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am using commerce_discount module to create a custom line item. Then inside my code I am creating a line item of type commerce_discount. I populate it and save it to order. It is saved but the line item total amount is not added to order total amount. The code is given below.

`$line_item_new = commerce_line_item_new('commerce_discount', $order->order_id);`

```
        $line_item_new->line_item_label = 'Discount';
        $line_item_new->quantity = 1;
        $line_item_new->commerce_unit_price['amount'] = $total_discount;
        $line_item_new->commerce_unit_price['currency'] = commerce_default_currency();
        $line_item_new->commerce_total['und'][0]['amount'] = -$amount;

        $order->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item_new;
        commerce_order_save($order);
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22614/order-total-not-updating-after-i-change-the-line-item-price ?

Comment: I've already opened that post, Let me try again with that.

Comment: Try again? You don't like answer there? Or you feel it's not what you ask about? If the second, could you edit your question to show how your case is different?

Comment: It's not working for me. I'm using line items of multiple types. like product, shipping, coupon and commerce_discount. The other are added, only commerce_discount is not added.

Comment: If you add them the same way, I don't understand. Good luck.