# Drupal Commerce order total amount not update after I programmatically changed line item's price

Tags: commerce

I am using Drupal Commerce. Now I have to alter the product price programmatically. After search on google and here, I found some people did it:
[Alter cart unit price and total amount](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46254/alter-cart-unit-price-and-total-amount)

Then I made a test by using hook_commerce_cart_order_refresh(). Here is my code:

```
function mymodule_commerce_cart_order_refresh($order_wrapper){
    foreach ($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
        $line_item = $line_item_wrapper->value();
        $qty = $line_item->quantity;
        $line_item->commerce_unit_price['und']['0']['amount']=100;
        $line_item->commerce_total['und']['0']['amount']=$qty*100;
        commerce_line_item_save($line_item);
    }
}
```

It changed the cart and order line item unit price and line item totoal amont. But the order total will not changed. Still calculated on the old price.

I also notice somebody have the same question:[Order Total not updating after I change the line item price](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22614/order-total-not-updating-after-i-change-the-line-item-price) , but I don't know that answer how it works. It said using following code:

The solution was to use commerce_price_add_component()

```
$line_item_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper("commerce_line_item", $commerce_line_item);
$line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->data = commerce_price_component_add(
    $line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->value(),
    'base_price',
    array(
            'amount' => $booking_price,
            'currency_code' => 'AUD',
            'data' => array(),
    ),
    TRUE
);
```

But I don't know where to use the above code, put in a hook?

Is some one can give me a idea?

Answer (score 2):

I'v found the way. Put answer here:

```
function mymodule_commerce_cart_line_item_refresh($line_item, $order_wrapper){
    $line_item->commerce_unit_price['und']['0']['amount']=110;
    $line_item->commerce_unit_price['und']['0']['data']['components']['0']['price']        ['amount']=110;
}
```

Because the commerce_order_calculate_total() is based on components, so if you only changed the commerce_unit_price amount is not enough. Must change data also.

Comment: How to apply in Drupal 8?